# cable too short to reattach into a sturmey archer 3 speed shifter

Tags: repair

I've just been given a Rayleigh Chiltern. The only problem is, the cable has unattached from the gear shifter. I Googled how to re thread, but the cable isn't long enough at the top end to slide right into the length of the shifter - it barely fits inside the shifter at all.

Can I use the excess cable at the hub end (if so how?) or am I just doing something wrong? Never done this before, so any advice would be massively welcome.

Comment: I suggest posting a photo of both ends of the cable.

Comment: Welcome to Bicycles SE. I just wanted to let you know that we ask that you [do not use signature lines](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/help/behavior) in your posts. We also typically remove "thank you's" and prefer that you say thanks by upvoting useful answers. Check out our [help pages](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/help) and our [tour](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/tour) for more info about how the site works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes if you have excess length at the hub end you can use that.  Just loosen the clamp on the hub and pull some slack.  Then you will need to reclamp at the hub and adjust.

If the cable is just plain to short then you will need to get a new cable.  Just take the existing to your LBS so they can match the end.

Answer (score 2):

Cables have special ends on the brake lever / shifter lever side which you need in order to hook the cable into the lever. A brake cable end for mountain bikes looks like:

[image]

You can't add these ends to an existing cable. If the cable is broken near the lever, then almost surely the part of the cable with the end is not going to be long enough. Thus, if you don't have a cable end, buy a new cable.

It's quite dangerous to have a broken brake cable, so you should get that fixed asap.

If you do have the appropriate cable with end, you just need to remove the cable tension (disconnect it), and then thread it through the part of the lever which can grab the cable as shown [here](http://www.parktool.com/blog/repair-help/brake-levers).

Comment: Gosh Batman, I feel soo dumb! Thanks for helping, and all your pics .. but it's the cable to the gear shifter, not, as I wrongly stated, the brake. Sorry!!!

Comment: And there is an end on the existing cable .. it's just that the cable's not long enough to slide right round the space in the gear shifter .. if that's any help?? Thanks again ..